# Bootstrap validator email regex

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using [bootstrap validator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/) but the email field accept "test@test". You can try it on my link. How can I do to fix that ? With the pattern attribute I can write a regex but I don't know do that.

I have already try this regex but all the emails are incorrect :

```php
<?php 
    echo $this->tag->emailField(
        array(
            "email", 
            "class" => "form-control", 
            "data-error" => "incorrect address",
            "pattern" => '/^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i',
            "required" => "required"
        )
    );
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you simply set the `type` property of `input` tag to `email` and let HTML5 do the validation for you.

You can also add a `pattern` attribute to specify a regex. You can get a very popular regex from following link:

[Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

```
pattern="^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$"
```

Comment: I use it but I want the bootstrap css dynamic with red / green color on the fields

Comment: The problem is the HTML5 validation. http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/ there is the same bug.

Comment: @John why are you wasting time in trying to validate email with such high accuracy, when client side validation can easily be bypassed - simple validation client side - and serious validation server side; if some one types abs@abc.abc (which) is syntactically correct but in reality doesn't exist every client validation will pass it though invalid.

Comment: This is just for the design. And I'm doing a validation server side too with Phalcon no problem.

Comment: Oh yes it works ! Thanks Thanks Thanks Thanks a lot ! You are awesome dude.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved my problem with this regex.

```
pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$"
```

Comment: this regex would consider a large number of valid emails as invalid

Comment: Oh I see :/. I'm trying with Valid email addresses int wikipedia and it doesn't work https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address

Comment: and this [^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6} ?